# jQuery unexpected identifier error

Tags: jquery

jQuery Code:

```
$("#ProjectType").change(function(){
    alert($("#ProjectType").val());
    if($("#ProjectType").val() == '16' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '17' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '18' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '19' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '20' ||response $("#ProjectType").val() == '21' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '22' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '23' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '24' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '25' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '26' || $("#ProjectType").val() == '27'){
        $("#BHKshow").hide();
        alert('if');
    }
    else{
        $("#BHKshow").show();
    }
})
```

It's displaying `unexpected identifier` error in console. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you also post the exact error string >?

Comment: Use proper IDE instead of notepad.

Comment: `if(... ||response $("#ProjectType").val() == '21' ...)` - what is `response`?

Comment: `var val = parseInt($("#ProjectType").val(), 10); if (val >= 16 && x <= 27) { ... } else { ... }` O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#ProjectType").change(function(){
    var projectValue = $("#ProjectType").val();
    alert(projectValue);
    if(projectValue == '16' || projectValue == '17' || projectValue == '18' || projectValue == '19' || projectValue == '20' || projectValue == '21' || projectValue == '22' || projectValue == '23' || projectValue == '24' || projectValue == '25' || projectValue == '26' || projectValue == '27'){
        $("#BHKshow").hide();
        alert('if');
    }
    else{
        $("#BHKshow").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be better to make the string value to integer, and then check it the integer is between those two numbers. Edit: just like @Andreas commented.